# DataTables custom header click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable( {
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false
                }]
            } );
        } );
    </script>

    <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table dt-responsive nowrap table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="no-sort">Country</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Matt</td>
                <td>Australia</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>matt@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nadine</td>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>nadine@outlook.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How do i merge column age and email into country? When the header for country was clicked, the tbody will display the respective column.

Comment: How do i merge column age and email into country? You mean `colspan`?

Comment: @AravindhGopi no like dropbox. where they have the options when the user clicks the header, they will change to different columns. Example there will only be 2 header. But the second header will display country, when the user clicks, it will change to age and when the user clicks again, it will change to email and when the user clicks again, it will change to country again. and it will loop from there

Comment: As I know, it means that the first your table only have 2 columns header : Name and Country. After you click Country header, it'll hide country and show Age column, right?

Comment: @Tomato32 yes that is exactly how i want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer my solution. Hope to help, my friend:

```
<table id="datatable-responsive" class="table dt-responsive nowrap table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th class="no-sort showHide">Country</th>
        <th class="showHide" >Age</th>
        <th class="showHide" >Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Matt</td>
            <td>Australia</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>matt@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nadine</td>
            <td>Indonesia</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>nadine@outlook.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {

        var columnShow = 3;

        //the first, hide Age and Email column
        $('#datatable-responsive td:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(3)').hide();
        $('#datatable-responsive td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').hide();

        $('.showHide').on('click', function () {

            //the first click show Age and hide Country column
            if (columnShow === 3) {
                $('#datatable-responsive td:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(3)').show(); 
                $('#datatable-responsive td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
                columnShow = 4;
                return;
            }

            //the second click show Email and hide Age column
            if (columnShow === 4) {
                $('#datatable-responsive td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').show();
                $('#datatable-responsive td:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(3)').hide();
                columnShow = 2;
                return;
            }

            //the next click show Country and hide Email column
            if (columnShow === 2) {
                $('#datatable-responsive td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').show();
                $('#datatable-responsive td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').hide();
                columnShow = 3;
                return;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Athira: Yeah. Just my suggestion. You can edit it :))

Comment: @Athira: You can explain more clearly. What happened after the first click, second click...